Change date format in a column with mixed field types
I'm prepping a report, which has columns with mixed field types (string, date, etc.)
The date format is what bothers me! Could you help me to figure out how to change it? I'm expecting it to look as "dd.MM.yyyy HH:MM".
The columns that are needed to be changed are l_st and new_val_name!
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT obj_name ,
          attr_name ,
          LAG(new_val_name) OVER (PARTITION BY attr_name ORDER BY stamp) l_st ,
          new_val_name ,
          employee_name,
          stamp
FROM SYS_AU_CHANGE_TYPE_ATTR change
WHERE OBJ_ID = :IDEC)

SELECT obj_name,
          attr_name,
          l_st,
          new_val_name,
          employee_name,
          stamp
          FROM t1 
          ORDER BY stamp DESC


Please provide sample data and expected results.  Sample data should ideally be in the form ´INSERT INTO demo(a, b, c) VALUES ...´, so that we don't have to do the work ourselves.

Try changing the line from -stamp to -TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS formatted_stamp
        WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT obj_name,
           attr_name,
           LAG(new_val_name) OVER (PARTITION BY attr_name ORDER BY stamp) l_st,
           new_val_name,
           employee_name,
           TO_CHAR(stamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS formatted_stamp
    FROM SYS_AU_CHANGE_TYPE_ATTR change
    WHERE OBJ_ID = :IDEC
)
SELECT obj_name,
       attr_name,
       l_st,
       new_val_name,
       employee_name,
       formatted_stamp
FROM t1
ORDER BY formatted_stamp DESC;


DD → day (two digits)
MM → month (two digits)
YYYY → year (four digits)
HH24 → hour in 24-hour format
MI → minute (two digits)


Hi! Thanks, but I need to change the format for l_st and new_val_name columns. to_char, format, etc. does not work as these columns also contain string and other formats.
